# Data binding inside Drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Guys I have one drop down with some data and I am doing following scenarios(for each letter am hitting server).

1.If I enter some data(which is already in drop down data) it will be selected[working fine].

2.If I enter some other data which is not present in drop down list, it will be added at the same time into drop down then user can select it.For that I wrote condition like this.[working fine]

```
if(result.success && result.items.length==0){
    var newData=term;
    var newObject={id:"",text:newData}
    return { results: $.merge([newObject], result.items)}                       
}
else if(result.success){
    return { results: $.merge([initialValue], result.items)}
}
```

3.If I enter new data(not presented in drop down)that should be added into drop down even `length!=0`. for example, 
       -->`andra pradesh`is already presented in dropdown.
 -->if I type `andana`(not in drop down) it will be added in drop down and user can select it for that I wrote condition(check above condition).
      -->now my question is if I type only `andra` (not `andra pradesh`)that should be added into drop down and user should be able select it.

How to modify my `if condition` for that last point?please give me some idea?

Comment: I got solution for this I just chenged the condition `length<=3` so that am getting expected result.But I need to insert my newly added data at last position of my list.its displaying in first position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just giving the idea how you can achieve it. replace dropdown.selected value and textbox.text with your fetched data.

```
if(result.success && result.items.length==0 || dropdown.SelectedValue != textbox.text ){
                                var newData=term;
                                var newObject={id:"",text:newData}
                                return { results: $.merge([newObject], result.items)}                       
                            }
                        else if(result.success){
                                return { results: $.merge([initialValue], result.items)}
                            }
```